# Filtering a single sample in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering

I'm attempting to create a reverb function in MATLAB and would like to filter the repeats to make them sound more natural. I have the signal processing toolbox however I get an error telling me that I cannot use the lowpass() function on single samples and MATLAB wigs out. The idea is to filter the signal every time it enters the feedback loop to simulate the absorption of high frequencies every time the sound reflects off a surface. My code looks like this:

```
[x,Fs] = audioread('Clap.mp3');


%Calculate delay length
secOfDelay = 0.03; %units of seconds
samplesOfDelay = secOfDelay * Fs; %sec * samples/sec = samples

%Gain for wet mix
g = 0.9;

for n = 1:length(x)
    if (n - samplesOfDelay) < 1 %For no past samples, don't add the delay yet.
        out(n,1) = x(n,1);
    else
        a(n,1) = x(n,1);
        b(n,1) = x(n,1) + (g * b(n-samplesOfDelay,1));
    end
end

%Add wet mix and dry mix together
out = a+b;

sound(out,Fs);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JDB

Comment: have you looked at filtering functions?

Comment: I am a bit confused: does sample mean *single time step* or *audio example*? If it is the first, well you will need to dig yourself deep into the theory of *recursive filtering*. There is no native MATLAB function for this. If it's the latter, you shouldn't have a problem